# MDADM software RAID infinite boot loop

Tags: raid, ubuntu-14.04, software-raid, mdadm

I'm currently following [this software RAID tutorial](http://sysadmin.compxtreme.ro/how-to-migrate-a-single-disk-linux-system-to-software-raid1/#comment-64277) and am at the point where I've prepared to boot off the second disk. So far I've done the following:

- Copied partition table from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb
- Changed the partition type to 'fd' on both /dev/sdb disks
- Created RAID arrays /dev/md1 and /dev/md2 using /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2
- mkfs.ext4 on /dev/md1 and mkswap on /dev/md2
- Created my mdadm.conf using mdadm --examine --scan
- mounted /dev/md1 to /mnt/md1 and copied /dev/sda1 to it
- Edited /etc/fstab to contain the blkid's of /deb/md1 and /dev/md2 instead of /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2
- Edited /etc/mtab to contain /dev/md1 instead of /dev/sda1
- Created a Grub menu entry using the proper linux kernel version name
- updated grub
- updated initramfs
- installed Grub on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

I've verified that the files are copied to the /dev/md1, that the /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab files reflect the UUIDs of the new array properly, and that the array is up and running.

Problem is, when I reboot I get stuck in an infinite loop after selecting the RAID menu entry from the grub menu. The machine immediately reboots and brings me back to the grub menu -- rinse and repeat. I've verified that my menu entry is correct and contains the proper root and I'm not getting any error messages. I'm just at a loss as to where to look for troubleshooting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really trying to convert a single disk system to RAID, or are you simply trying to create a system with software  Raid? Either way, there are multiple serious problems with the steps you describe.

Comment: System with software RAID -- with the exact setup outlined in the tutorial I linked to (2 disks of exactly the same size, one with an OS already installed on it).  It's already working fine on one of my machines.